# Savefig outputs blank image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, figure

I am trying to save plots I make using matplotlib; however, the images are saving blank.

Here is my code:

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(dataStack, cmap=mpl.cm.bone)

plt.subplot(122)
y = copy.deepcopy(tumorStack)
y = np.ma.masked_where(y == 0, y)

plt.imshow(dataStack, cmap=mpl.cm.bone)
plt.imshow(y, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, interpolation='nearest')

if T0 is not None:
    plt.subplot(123)
    plt.imshow(T0, cmap=mpl.cm.bone)

    #plt.subplot(124)
    #Autozoom

#else:
    #plt.subplot(124)
    #Autozoom

plt.show()
plt.draw()
plt.savefig('tessstttyyy.png', dpi=100)
```

And tessstttyyy.png is blank (also tried with .jpg)

Answer (score 501, accepted):

First, what happens when `T0 is not None`? I would test that, then I would adjust the values I pass to `plt.subplot()`; maybe try values 131, 132, and 133, or values that depend whether or not `T0` exists.

Second, after `plt.show()` is called, a new figure is created. To deal with this, you can

1. Call `plt.savefig('tessstttyyy.png', dpi=100)` before you call `plt.show()`
2. Save the figure before you `show()` by calling `plt.gcf()` for "get current figure", then you can call `savefig()` on this `Figure` object at any time.

For example:

```
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
fig1.savefig('tessstttyyy.png', dpi=100)
```

In your code, 'tesssttyyy.png' is blank because it is saving the new figure, to which nothing has been plotted.

Comment: Forgot to remove the T0 part...it was commented previously.

Comment: A special case of this occurs in `jupyter` notebooks with `%matplotlib inline` enabled: the `savefig` call must be in the same cell as the plot creation method.

Comment: Interesting to see `plt.show()` generates a new image. Indeed, this solved the issue.

Comment: Interestingly, if you type plt.plot, plt.savefig, plt.show one by one in terminal such as spyder, it will not show fig. Put all command in a script and run in one go. It shows the plot.

Comment: @CKM Hi. Do you happen to know why this happens? I was thinking it's actually a problem that causes functions like `plt.ylabel()` create a new figure instead of applying to the current one (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794236/matplotlib-pyplot-functions-creating-new-figures-instead-of-applyting-to-the-cur)), and also saving figures blank. I plotted a figure and saved it in the same line (separated by `;`) and it worked. Is this just a problem with Spyder?

Comment: I've tried all answers in this post and still nothing works. It runs without errors and creates the file just fine

Answer (score 268):

`plt.show()` should come after `plt.savefig()`

Explanation: `plt.show()` clears the whole thing, so anything afterwards will happen on a new empty figure

Answer (score 37):

change the order of the functions **fixed the problem** for me:

- **first** **Save** the plot
- **then** **Show** the plot

as following:

```
plt.savefig('heatmap.png')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

Calling savefig before show() worked for me.

```
fig ,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (4,4))
sns.barplot(x='sex', y='tip', color='g', ax=ax,data=tips)
sns.barplot(x='sex', y='tip', color='b', ax=ax,data=tips)
ax.legend(['Male','Female'], facecolor='w')

plt.savefig('figure.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

let's me give a more detail example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def draw_result(lst_iter, lst_loss, lst_acc, title):
    plt.plot(lst_iter, lst_loss, '-b', label='loss')
    plt.plot(lst_iter, lst_acc, '-r', label='accuracy')

    plt.xlabel("n iteration")
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.savefig(title+".png")  # should before plt.show method

    plt.show()


def test_draw():
    lst_iter = range(100)
    lst_loss = [0.01 * i + 0.01 * i ** 2 for i in xrange(100)]
    # lst_loss = np.random.randn(1, 100).reshape((100, ))
    lst_acc = [0.01 * i - 0.01 * i ** 2 for i in xrange(100)]
    # lst_acc = np.random.randn(1, 100).reshape((100, ))
    draw_result(lst_iter, lst_loss, lst_acc, "sgd_method")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_draw()
```

[image]