# Pandas Data Frame Plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have this Pandas DataFrame

[image]

which gives me this:

[image]

How do I

1. Make a new figure,
2. Add the title to the figure "Title Here"
3. Somehow create a mapping so that instead of the labels being 29,30 etc, they say "week 29", "Week 30"etc.
4. Save a larger version of the chart to my computer (say 10 x 10 inches)

I have been puzzling over this for an hour now!

Comment: It's much easier to include the actual text of the DataFrame rather than an image, ie copy and paste, highlight and use CTRL+k (which indents by 4 spaces).

Comment: Plus that HTML frame will probably show up very nicely :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) DataFrame method:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 5),
                          index=['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
                          columns=[29, 30, 31, 32, 33])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
           29        30        31        32        33
Mon -0.080946 -0.072797 -1.019406  1.149162  2.727502
Tue  1.041598 -0.730701 -0.079450  1.323332 -0.823343
Wed  0.338998  1.034372 -0.273139  0.457153  0.007429
Thu -2.239857 -0.439499  0.675963  0.966994  1.348100
Fri  0.050717 -0.506382  1.269897 -0.862577  1.205110
Sat -1.380323  0.200088 -0.685536 -0.425614  0.148111
Sun -0.248540 -1.056943  1.550433  0.651707 -0.041801

In [3]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: 'Week ' + str(x), inplace=True)

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
      Week 29   Week 30   Week 31   Week 32   Week 33
Mon -0.080946 -0.072797 -1.019406  1.149162  2.727502
Tue  1.041598 -0.730701 -0.079450  1.323332 -0.823343
Wed  0.338998  1.034372 -0.273139  0.457153  0.007429
Thu -2.239857 -0.439499  0.675963  0.966994  1.348100
Fri  0.050717 -0.506382  1.269897 -0.862577  1.205110
Sat -1.380323  0.200088 -0.685536 -0.425614  0.148111
Sun -0.248540 -1.056943  1.550433  0.651707 -0.041801
```

You can then plot this with a title:

```
In [4]: df.plot(title='Title Here')
```

See more in the [visualisation section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

*Note: [to save the figure you can use savefig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/matplotlib-save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-so-can-be-used-in-b).*

Answer (score 12):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# 1, 4
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10)) # Change the size as necessary
# 2
dataframe.plot(ax=f.gca()) # figure.gca means "get current axis"
plt.title('Title here!', color='black')
# 3
# Not sure :(
```