# Save/export axes/plot area to file, not figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is no shortage of [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9622163/2071807) about saving a matplotlib figure to a file. This is easy using `fig.savefig(filename)`.

But what if I want to save *only the plot area itself*, not the x- and y-axes, the outline of the plot or the title etc.

For example, I would like to export only the area [shown in red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/253241) below to either a `.pdf` or a `.png`:
[image: Plot area]

Comment: could you not just set `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)` before you savefig? then you will lose all the titles, labels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by simply adding the following lines in your code

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("test.png",bbox_inches='tight')
```

plt.axis('off') hides your axis and bbox_inches='tight' crops the picture of the white spaces where the axis were.

Comment: This is pretty good. Is there a way to do `plt.axis('off`)` without using the `pyplot` object? I tend to work with `ax` and `fig` objects. (I do `fig.tight_layout()` for the `bbox_inches` thing.