# how to save feature map to a image for visualization in terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, caffe

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  7 def vis_square(data):
  8     """Take an array of shape (n, height, width) or (n, height, width, 3)
  9        and visualize each (height, width) thing in a grid of size approx. sqrt(n) by     sqrt(n)"""
 10     # normalize data for display
 11     data = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min())
 12
 13     # force the number of filters to be square
 14     n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(data.shape[0])))
 15     padding = (((0, n ** 2 - data.shape[0]),
 16                (0, 1), (0, 1))                 # add some space between filters
 17                + ((0, 0),) * (data.ndim - 3))  # don't pad the last dimension (if th    ere is one)
 18     data = np.pad(data, padding, mode='constant', constant_values=1)  # pad with one    s (white)
 19
 20     # tile the filters into an image
 21     data = data.reshape((n, n) + data.shape[1:]).transpose((0, 2, 1, 3) + tuple(rang    e(4, data.ndim + 1)))
 22     data = data.reshape((n * data.shape[1], n * data.shape[3]) + data.shape[4:])
 23     #plt.imshow(data);plt.axis('off') ### THIS LINE DOESNT WORK IN TERMINAL
        fig,ax = plt.imshow(data)
        fig.savefig('fig.png')
```

I work in a shared server, thus no gui is provided. But I want to see what's the feature look like?

line: 23 doesn't work in terminal.

how can I save the data to an image? plz advise.

---

I solve the task by save the data file to a pickle, and then draw the picture in another computer. But still interested in the method of drawing the picture in a virtual picture and save the image on the server.

---

Use a `backend'. Check this [doc](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

```
 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.use('Agg')
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib (so it can be used in batch scripts for example)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib-so-it-can-be)

Comment: Have you tried using `savefig` ? -- Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib-so-it-can-be)

Comment: @Gator_Python i check the post, but still not get the picture. can you add brief answer.