# Python script in AngularJs

Tags: python, angularjs, node.js

I am new to JavaScript, I am working on a web-app which has NodeJs as server-framework and AngularJs as application framework. I would like to run a python script which displays graphs(matplotlib) on the view/template. Here is the python code. The process of fetching data from mongodb server can be done in NodeJs controller.

```
# In[2]:

import pymongo
import json
import datetime as dt
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# In[77]:

l=['ts','cd']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=l)
k=0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
    db=client.test
    collection=db['data']
    cursor = collection.find({"dId":3},{"ts":1,"cd":1}).sort("ts",-1).limit(25000)
    for document in cursor:
        df.loc[k,'ts']=document.values()[1]
        df.loc[k,'cd']=document.values()[2]
        k=k+1


# In[78]:

times = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df.ts))    

# In[79]:

times['hour']=times['ts'].dt.hour
times['date']=times['ts'].dt.date
times['weekday']=times['ts'].dt.weekday


# In[80]:

grouped = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','hour','weekday','count'])
grouped[['date','hour','weekday','count']] = times.groupby(['date','hour','weekday']).count().reset_index()


# In[81]:

irregularities=grouped[grouped['count'] != 60][['date','hour','weekday','count']]


# In[82]:

get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
x = irregularities['weekday']
plt.hist(x, bins=30)
plt.ylabel('Count of irregularities')
plt.xlabel('day of week')
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],['mon','tue','wed','thurs','fri','sat','sun'])


# In[86]:

x = irregularities['hour']
plt.hist(x, bins=30)
plt.ylabel('Count of irregularities')
plt.xlabel('Hour of day')
```

I can't figure out how to integrate this python script in Angular Js. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python can't be run in browser. So you can [render your graph to png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib) and [output it to client using node](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell).

Alternatively there is [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/index.html) library that does almost exactly what you need

Comment: Thank you for your help!