# How to save an image plotted with matplolib 1.5

Tags: python

I want to save an image plotted with matplotlib. For that, I use the function savefig which has different parameters. 
The problem is that when I saved the image, this function add additional white pixel.

In short, I would like to save the image I draw with the original size. In other words, if the data I draw has a dimension of 1000x560, I save the image with those dimensions without additional white parts.
Thus in this way a pixel of the saved image coincides with the pixel that the figure of matplotlib can see.

I'm using python 2.7

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```