# matplotlib: How to create original backend

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following program does not work on non-GUI environments.
I want to let this program save the figure to a temporary png file when `plt.show` is called.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(2,3)
plt.scatter(4,5)
plt.show()
```

I know that this can be resolved by using `plt.savefig` instead of `plt.show` (cf. [Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib)) . But I don't want to change the program itself. The program may be given by other user who may familiar with using matplotlib in GUI environments.

So I consider to change the backend of matplotlib into my own backend which changes behavior of `show`. It can be done by changing `matplotlibrc`.
But the document about backend only explains how to select "built-in" backends:
https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html?highlight=backend#coding-styles

The document says that backend can be specified as `module://my_backend`, but it does not define the "interface" of `my_backend` ( what kind of Classes/Object should be implemented in which names? )

Is there any documents which explains the interface of backends? (Or some other workaround change behavior of `show`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most minimal backend could look like this, where we just take the figure canvas from the agg backend (and are hence able to use all associated methods)

```
from matplotlib.backend_bases import Gcf
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

FigureCanvas = FigureCanvasAgg

def show(*args, **kwargs):
    for num, figmanager in enumerate(Gcf.get_all_fig_managers()):
        figmanager.canvas.figure.savefig(f"figure_{num}.png")
```

If you save this as `mybackend.py`, you can use it as backend via `matplotlib.use("module://mybackend")`.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("module://mybackend")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,3,2])

plt.figure()
plt.scatter([1,2,3], [3,2,3], color="crimson")

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need but it doesn't always work. This works: `plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,1,4]); plt.show()`, but this does not: `fig = plt.figure(); fig.gca().plot([1,2,3],[3,3,1]); fig.show()`. I get the following warning message: `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://pyptex, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.` This apparently comes from `FigureManagerBase.show()`. Is there a quick way of fixing this?

Comment: Ah, it seems you should make a custom FigureManager. I wasn't able to paste the code in this comment though...

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfortunately having to create a separate answer, but this is really in addition to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155266/959894). You also need to create a `FigureManager`, or else you'll get a cryptic `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://mybackend, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.` if you try to `show()` a `plt.fig()`. My extra code thus far is this:

```
from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureManagerBase

class FigureManager(FigureManagerBase):
    def show(self):
        self.canvas.figure.savefig('foo.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

You also asked if there's any documentation that explains the backend interface.

There is: there's a backend called 'template' in the matplotlib source code, with comments that describe the interface.

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_template.py