# Problems with saving numpy array as an image

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have troubles with saving numpy two-dimensional array as image (in grayscale). I read this question [Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib/32287336), but still don't understand what's wrong with the following code.

```
plt.imsave("image.eps", np.flipud(arr), cmap = "gray_r", format = "eps", dpi = 1000)
```

After execution the image.eps is blank and I don't understand why. I also tried to deal with it as an AxesImage object (see below) but without success.

```
img = plt.imshow(np.flipud(arr))
plt.savefig("image.eps", format = "eps", dpi = 1000)
```

Please, explain me what's wrong with this code.

Actually, I am new to Python (and to matplotlib as well), so I am not familiar with many ideas of Python.

**Update:**
I tried the following code but the image.eps is still blank.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 0.5],[0.5, 0]])

plt.imsave("image.eps", np.flipud(arr), cmap = "gray_r", format = "eps", dpi = 1000)
```

On the other hand if I call

```
img = plt.imshow(arr)
```

then I can see in the console (Spyder) the correct picture (one black, one white and two gray squares).

Maybe there is some way to save the picture using the img-variable?

Comment: Can you include the array that you are using? Or at least a subset of it?

Comment: With `arr = np.arange(10000).reshape(100,100)`, your `imsave` syntax works (though the image is only 1 inch wide) . So you need to be more specific.

Comment: I suspect one major problem is that eps, like other vector formats, does not really have a dpi defined. This may have some strange implications if the canonical "dpi" of 72 is completely different from the set dpi (here 1000).

Comment: Yes, indeed, code without setting dpi works. However, the corresponding picture is too small (even for matrices 500\times 500 that I use). Is it possible to make picture bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested `imsave`in my interpreter

```
In [39]: import numpy as np 
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                  

In [40]: a = np.random.random((500,500))                                                  

In [41]: plt.imsave('a1000.eps', a, dpi=1000)                                             

In [42]: plt.imsave('a0500.eps', a, dpi=500)                                              

In [43]:                                                                                  
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? 
22:07 boffi@debian:~ $ ll a1000.eps a0500.eps 
-rw-r--r-- 1 boffi boffi 1512480 Nov 22 22:07 a0500.eps
-rw-r--r-- 1 boffi boffi 1512480 Nov 22 22:07 a1000.eps
```

As you can see, the two files have identical sizes, are they equal or are they different?

```
22:08 boffi@debian:~ $ diff a1000.eps a0500.eps 
2c2
< %%Title: a1000.eps
---
> %%Title: a0500.eps
4c4
< %%CreationDate: Fri Nov 22 22:07:30 2019
---
> %%CreationDate: Fri Nov 22 22:07:42 2019
6c6
< %%BoundingBox: 288.0 378.0 324.0 414.0
---
> %%BoundingBox: 270.0 360.0 342.0 432.0
31,32c31,32
< 288 378 translate
< 36 36 0 0 clipbox
---
> 270 360 translate
> 72 72 0 0 clipbox
37c37
< 36.0 36.0 scale
---
> 72.0 72.0 scale
```

As you can see, the differences are only in the postscript code, especially the `scale` command has interestingly different parameters... on the contrary we see that the raw data representing the matrix is *exactly* the same in the two files.  This is consistent with the description of `dpi` in the `imsave` doc string

> ```
> dpi : int
>       The DPI to store in the metadata of the file.  This does not affect the
>       resolution of the output image.
> ```

Finally, we have the problem that your images are blank.  Mine are not. Note that the larger image is the one with lesser `dpi`, this is contrary to your belief that increasing the `dpi` you'll get a larger picture.

[image][image]