# plt.savefig does not work in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a Python beginner. When I was trying to save figure in Jupyter notebook using the code `plt.savefig("figure.png")`, it generated an error message of

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_send_event'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: .p]

Comment: please post code about how you get the figure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib)