# How to save figures instead of plot it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this part of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(1, 5, 1):
    x, y = valid_gen.__getitem__(i)
    result = model.predict(x)
    result = result > 0.4

    for i in range(len(result)):
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)

        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
        ax.imshow(np.reshape(y[i] * 255, (image_size, image_size)), cmap="gray")

        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
        ax.imshow(np.reshape(result[i] * 255, (image_size, image_size)), cmap="gray")
```

But I am getting an error when I am trying to plot it:

```
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory.
```

So I want to save figures instead to plot it, how should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib)

Comment: But what should I do with `ax.imshow`?

Comment: ```fig.savefig('path/name.png')``` should do it.
Heres the corresponding documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Comment: But should I delete `ax.imshow(np.reshape(y[i] * 255, (image_size, image_size)), cmap="gray")` and `ax.imshow(np.reshape(result[i] * 255, (image_size, image_size)), cmap="gray")` ? How program knows what it should be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, modify the index of your inner loop. It is currently the same as the outer loop, which you do not want. Set it to `j` for example.

Regarding your figure issue, append the following to your inner loop.

```
fig.savefig(f'Figure{i}_{j}.png')
plt.close(fig)
```

EDIT:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(1, 5, 1):
    x, y = valid_gen.__getitem__(i)
    result = model.predict(x)
    result = result > 0.4
    for j in range(len(result)):
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
        ax.imshow(np.reshape(y[j] * 255, (image_size, image_size)),
                  cmap='gray')
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
        ax.imshow(np.reshape(result[j] * 255, (image_size, image_size)),
                  cmap='gray')
        fig.savefig(f'Figure{i}_{j}.png')
        plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: But should I delete `ax.imshow(np.reshape(y[i] * 255, (image_size, image_size)), cmap="gray")` and `ax.imshow(np.reshape(result[i] * 255, (image_size, image_size)), cmap="gray")` ? How program knows what it should be saved?

Comment: Do not delete those lines. Each subplot axis is created by the add_subplot method of your Figure object fig. As a consequence, calling imshow on each of these axes renders the data on the Figure object associated to those axes, which indeed is fig in your case. Simply save your figure at the end of the inner loop and close the figure to avoid memory filling.

Comment: Can you write your lines into my code please? I still don't understand. Sorry, I am new in python

Answer (score 0):

You can save a figure by using 
`plt.savefig("figure-name.png")`

Additionally to remove white spaces in the figure use
`plt.savefig('figure-name.png', bbox_inches='tight')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.savefig('name.png')
```