# How to fix error with saving plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(24, 9))
function_names = ['Loss', 'Accuracy']
stats_names = iter(list(stats.keys()))

for i in range(2):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, i+1)
    ax.plot(range(config['n_train_epoch']),
            stats[next(stats_names)], 
            label='Validation', 
            color='darkorchid', 
            lw=2.5)
    ax.plot(range(config['n_train_epoch']), 
            stats[next(stats_names)], 
            label='Training', 
            color='mediumspringgreen', 
            lw=2.5)
    ax.set_xlabel('Number of training epochs')
    ax.set_ylabel(function_names[i] + ' value')
    ax.set_title(function_names[i] + ' Functions', fontsize=20)
    ax.legend(fontsize=14)
```

And i`m getting this [plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utnrp.png).

I want to save it to png, but when i refactor my code to this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(24, 9))
function_names = ['Loss', 'Accuracy']
stats_names = iter(list(stats.keys()))

for i in range(2):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, i+1)
    ax.plot(range(config['n_train_epoch']),
            stats[next(stats_names)], 
            label='Validation', 
            color='darkorchid', 
            lw=2.5)
    ax.plot(range(config['n_train_epoch']), 
            stats[next(stats_names)], 
            label='Training', 
            color='mediumspringgreen', 
            lw=2.5)
    ax.set_xlabel('Number of training epochs')
    ax.set_ylabel(function_names[i] + ' value')
    ax.set_title(function_names[i] + ' Functions', fontsize=20)
    ax.legend(fontsize=14)

plt.savefig('results/graphics.png')
```

i`m getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVB5P.png)

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib ?

Comment: [`plt.savefig('yourPlotName')`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)

Comment: @Ch3ster question has been edited

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib provides [savefig](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) which supports `png` and other formats.

You could, for example, do:

```
plt.gcf().savefig('plot.png', dpi=150)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend instantiating your figures and axes directly.  It's much easier to manipulate and save plots.

For example,

```
with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # Plot something using `ax`
    fig.savefig("path/to/output.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```