# When creating an image with matplotlib, where are the graphical instances stored?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to undestand what happens if I run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2], [5, 2])
plt.plot([1, 2], [4, 4])
plt.show()
```

How does plt.show() know, that it has to plot two lines in one plot? According to `help(plt.plot)` twice "A list of `.Line2D` objects representing the plotted data" is returned; but where are they stored? Since `plt` is still of type "module", I don't see it as an instance where the data are stored. In R a ggplot instance is created by `my_plot <- ggplot(...)`, and then this object `gg` could be sent to someone else who could modify this object as he wishes (for example to add axis labels in his own language) and only with `show(gg)`, the image is generated (see for example [here](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html)).

For matplotlib, I only found [how to export the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib), but not how to export the graphical instance "below" the image.

Comment: If no figure is created by the script, then `plt.plot` creates its own figure and axes. You can get the current figure and axes objects using `plt.gcf()` and `plt.gca()` respectively

Comment: By "figure created by the script", do you mean "fig = plt.figure()"?