# Matplotlib, prevent plot from showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

```
df_rm_count[['count']].sort_values(by='count', ascending=False).plot.barh()
```

The above line shows the graph (without `plt.show()`)

I'd like to save the plot as image but can't because `plot` immediately displays the plot

I tried

- `%matplotlib` (to negate `%matplotlib inline` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'` error)
- plt.ioff()
- plt.close('all')
- matplotlib.pyplot.close(fig)
- matplotlib.interactive(False)

none of the above worked..

- edit

Agg didn't work either..

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')

ipykernel_launcher.py:2: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called
*before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot, or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

Comment: Your question has been answered here. Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib

Comment: I don't get how I can draw using `df.plot.bar() ` without `show` .. the questions is about `fig.plot()` which may be same thing internally, but I can't decypher what to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different backend that cannot display a figure, for example `Agg`

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
```

---

In order to not restart the kernel, put `plt.switch_backend('Agg')` right below the lines that create `fig` and `ax`, for example

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.switch_backend('Agg')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1,2,3]
df['a'].plot.barh(ax=ax)
```

Comment: I guess I can run it if I restart the kernel.. which I want to avoid atm..

Comment: @eugene You can switch backend if you don't want to restart the kernel, check out my updated post.