# How to save these images in grayscale without displaying them?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, imshow

Only way I know to save images in grayscale is by using imshow, but the problem with this is it displays/prints the image which I don't want. Is there another way to save in grayscale without printing?
This is the code:

```
savethis=gen_imgs

for i in range(r*c):
    #img=1
    img=plt.imshow(savethis[i, :,:,0],cmap='gray_r')
    img=plt.axis('off')
    img=plt.savefig('/Users/User/Documents/UCSDproject/SV_cluster/' + str(i)+'.jpg')
```

Comment: You can, for example, use `cv2`: `cv2.imwrite('file_path.jpg', savethis[i,:,:,0])`.

Comment: Do you want to save the ACTUAL IMAGE? Then, follow [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168313/11089932). If you want to save the PLOT OF THE IMAGE simply without showing, follow [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib).

Answer (score 1):

Amongst others, you can use:

- **PIL** `Image.fromarray(grey).save('result.jpg')`
- **OpenCV** `cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', grey)`
- **imageio**
- **wand**
- **vips**
- **tifffile**