# Problem with saving the plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use `plt.savefig(pngpath, dpi=300)`, where the pngpath is the path where I want it to save. The png file as such is being created but is blank when I try and open it. Interestingly, the `plt.show()` right before this `plt.savefig()` works perfectly fine.

EDIT 1: As ONDRO pointed out, I used plt.show() after plt.savefig() and the plot saved perfectly as intended. Also, I will make sure to add minimal reproduceable code next time. Thank you ONDRO and everyone else for helping me out!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with a reproducible amount of code so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: If you are doing this in jupyter, make sure `savefig()` is in the same cell as your plotting code. If `savefig()` is in a separate cell, the output file will be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pyplot` interface, you have to call `plt.savefig()` before `plt.show()`. If you change the order, the figure is destroyed once the window is closed and a new empty one is created by `plt.savefig()`.

Answer (score 0):

So you haven't posted your code so I can't debug it for you. But try running this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583288/7916220) and adepting it to your own.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.savefig('myfig')
```