# matplotlib save plot instead of displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python on a linux shell and trying to save plot instead of displaying (displaying plot window leads to an error). I looked at question [Save plot to image file instead of displaying it using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9622163/11638153), but didn't help. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#
# list3 is list of data
plt.hist(list3, bins=10)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
fig.savefig('plot.png')
```

The problem is figure window is appearing even though I don't call `plt.figure()`. Is there any way to suppress graphical figure window and instead save plot to the file?

Comment: using your code I'm not able to reproduce your error. ```plt.show()```display the figure, ```plt.figure()``` is supposed to be written before ```plt.hist``` if you want to tune some parameters (or display multiple figures for example).

Answer (score 1):

`plt.savefig('plot.png')` saves the png file for me. May be you need to give full path for the file