# How to insert Matplotlib pie chart in this program?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know how I'd go about adding a MatPlotLib pie chart in this piece of code? I've been trying for hours but the figure popup just hangs or can't be opened.

````
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow
import psutil
import time
import win32process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()

process_time={}
timestamp = {}
while True:
    current_app = psutil.Process(win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow())[1]).name().replace(".exe", "")
    timestamp[current_app] = int(time.time())
    time.sleep(1)
    if current_app not in process_time.keys():
        process_time[current_app] = 0
    process_time[current_app] = process_time[current_app]+int(time.time())-timestamp[current_app]

    if process_time[current_app] > 15:
        toaster.show_toast("If something is cracked","Glue it!!!",icon_path='yeet notifi/amogus.ico')
       """ labels = []
        sizes = []
        for x, y in process_time.items():
            labels.append(x)
            sizes.append(y)
        plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels)
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.show()
        time.sleep(3)
        plt.close('all')
        #plt.pause() """


    print(process_time) ```
The area with the """ is the area that I need the code it. It works for now but just hangs and can't be moved around. Is it something to do with the loop?

All help appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with how your editor renders the figures sequentially. I would recommend exporting the plots as images instead. Since you are using a while loop, initialize a counter variable `count=1` outside the loop.

Save the image. (Snippet taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib))

```
>>> plt.savefig(f'plot_{count}.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Then increment the counter

```
>>> counter += 1
```