# matplotlib fill_between facecolor alpha vs edgecolor alpha?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to either specify different alphas for `facecolor` vs `edgecolor`? Or is there a way to plot an alpha filled area with non-alpha edgecolor *that also works in the legend*?

This is not what I want...
[image]

```
axs.fill_between(xvalues, tupper_w, tlower_w, facecolor='dimgray', edgecolor='dimgray', alpha=0.25, label='$measured\quad\sigma$')
axs.fill_between(xvalues, pupper_w, plower_w, facecolor='orange', edgecolor='orange', alpha=0.25, label='$predicted\quad\sigma$')
axs.plot(xvalues, tcurvesavg_w, color='dimgray', label='$\overline{measured}$', ls='--')
axs.plot(xvalues, pcurvesavg_w, color='orange', label='$\overline{predicted}$', ls='--')
```

This is what I want (but with proper legend):
[image]

```
axs.fill_between(xvalues, tupper, tlower, facecolor='dimgray', alpha=0.25, label='$measured\quad\sigma$')
axs.fill_between(xvalues, pupper, plower, facecolor='orange', alpha=0.25, label='$predicted\quad\sigma$')
axs.plot(xvalues, tupper, color='dimgray', lw=0.5)
axs.plot(xvalues, tcurvesavg, color='dimgray', label='$\overline{measured}$', ls='--')
axs.plot(xvalues, tlower, color='dimgray', lw=0.5)
axs.plot(xvalues, pupper, color='orange', lw=0.5)
axs.plot(xvalues, pcurvesavg, color='orange', label='$\overline{predicted}$', ls='--')
axs.plot(xvalues, plower, color='orange', lw=0.5)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot specify different alpha values via the `alpha` argument. However you can define each of `facecolor` and `edgecolor` with an alpha channel, e.g. for red with 40% opacity

```
facecolor=(1,0,0,.4)
```

This is then directly applied in the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = 1.2*np.sin(4*np.pi*x)-.9

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.fill_between(x, y1, y1+.5, facecolor=(1,0,0,.4), edgecolor=(0,0,0,.5), label="Label 1")
ax.fill_between(x, y2, y2-.5, facecolor=(0,0,1,.4), edgecolor=(0,0,0,.5), label="Label 1")

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Immediately, looking at [fill_between alpha](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/fill_between_alpha.html) and general [fill_between documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between) it appears to be unsupported. The [legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) doesn't seem to provide an option for adding your border after plotting either.

In your second code snippet, if you can figure out how to get the plot and fill functions to have a single handle then the legend should automatically format. Something similar to below (adapted from [this similar, but not quite duplicate StackExchangePost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732845/combine-two-pyplot-patches-for-legend)):

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xvalues = np.linspace(0,1,11)
tcurvesavg = np.linspace(0,1,11)
p1, = plt.plot(xvalues, tcurvesavg , c='r')  # notice the comma!
p2 = plt.fill_between(xvalues, tcurvesavg -0.2, tcurvesavg +0.2, color='r', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(((p1,p2),), ('Entry',))
plt.show()
```

(As a non-automated workaround for most matplotlib questions, save as a svg (similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525111/how-can-i-get-the-output-of-a-matplotlib-plot-as-an-svg)) and add a border in a vector graphics program like Inkscape. You shouldn't lose resolution, and could still put it in reports etc.)

Comment: I will try that, thx! And yea, I was going to post-process the final ones if no procedural solution could be found. I'm generating hundreds of different plots across all my experiments, so I was trying to make sure it worked from the start. But post-process is necessary sometimes :/

Comment: @delrocco *TheImportanceOfBeingErnest*'s answer absolutely does what you are looking for, you should mark it as accepted.