# Create a detailed svg graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, svg, resolution

I use the Python library `matplotlib` to draw a graph with a lot of data. Upon executing `plt.show()` I can zoom in and see the details of the graph. However, I would like to save the graph into a svg file with `plt.savefig` and see these details which by default are not visible from the default non-zoomed-in view. How can I do that?

Please, note that increasing DPI or inch by inch dimensions is meaningless when working with vector graphics formats such as the svg file.

As an example, consider the following program.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.arange(0,100,0.00001)
y = x*np.sin(2*math.pi*(x**1.2))
plt.plot(y)
plt.savefig('test.svg')
```

We will get the following plot which even when we zoom, we cannot see the details of the sine wave periods.[image]

But we can see the details of the sine wave when displaying the image with `plt.show` instead and then zooming in.[image]

Comment: The saved svg should have all the details you need. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525111/how-can-i-get-the-output-of-a-matplotlib-plot-as-an-svg) might be helpful. Note that increasing the dimension does help as `1/72" per unit` is used.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It does not have all the details. I edited the post with an example that demonstrates my claim.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the link. I adapted the example from there to demonstrate my problem. As you can see in the program I provided in the edit, I do not use any background and axis markers. Hence the linked post still does not solve my problem.

Comment: You need to set a thinner line if you want to see something when zoomed in for that example. `plt.plot(y, linewidth=0.1)`

Comment: @JohanC Thank you. With `linewidth=0.1` the problem was resolved too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the size of the figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.arange(0,100,0.00001)
y = x*np.sin(2*math.pi*(x**1.2))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19.20,10.80))

plt.plot(y)
plt.savefig('test.svg')
```

and you get the kind of resolution you wish.

---

As correctly observed by JohanC, another good solution is to reduce the width of the line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.arange(0,100,0.00001)
y = x*np.sin(2*math.pi*(x**1.2))
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19.20,10.80))

plt.plot(y, linewidth=0.1)
plt.savefig('test.svg')
```

Comment: If you don't adapt the linewidth, you still won't see much when zoomed in.  If you do adapt the linewidth and don't set a figsize, the image looks fine when zoomed in.