# How can I save histogram plot in python?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have following code that generates a histogram. How can I save the histogram automatically using the code? I tried what we do for other plot types but that did not work for histogram.a is a 'numpy.ndarray'.

```
a = [-0.86906864 -0.72122614 -0.18074998 -0.57190212 -0.25689268 -1.
     0.68713553  0.29597819  0.45022949  0.37550592  0.86906864  0.17437203
     0.48704826  0.2235648   0.72122614  0.14387731  0.94194514 ]

fig = pl.hist(a,normed=0)
pl.title('Mean')
pl.xlabel("value")
pl.ylabel("Frequency")
pl.savefig("abc.png")
```

Answer (score 15):

This works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

a = np.array([-0.86906864, -0.72122614, -0.18074998, -0.57190212, -0.25689268 ,-1. ,0.68713553 ,0.29597819, 0.45022949, 0.37550592, 0.86906864, 0.17437203, 0.48704826, 0.2235648, 0.72122614, 0.14387731, 0.94194514])

fig = pl.hist(a,normed=0)
pl.title('Mean')
pl.xlabel("value")
pl.ylabel("Frequency")
pl.savefig("abc.png")
```

`a` in the OP is not a numpy array and its format also needs to be modified (it needs commas, not spaces as delimiters). This program successfully saves the histogram in the working directory. If it still does not work, supply it with a full path to the location where you want to save it like this

```
pl.savefig("/Users/atru/abc.png")
```

The `pl.show()` statement should not be placed before `savefig()` as it creates a new figure which makes `savefig()` save a blank figure instead of the desired one as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image) post.

Comment: @ atru: Yes, I am using matplotlib. I tried the way you suggested but it saves an empty png file.

Comment: Can you share more of your code then? It works perfect for me. In fact I was pretty happy with the quality.

Comment: @ atru: I have edited the code in the question section with savefig. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: Can you also add what is `a`?

Comment: Works for me (your complete sequence) for `a = np.random.randn(1000)`. Try specifying the full path to the directory where you want to save the file.

Comment: I just added information about a in the question. Would you please check.

Comment: Is this your real code? Because if it is then it should throw an error. I fixed it, see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, this is a real code. I am not sure why but this still does not works on my side. a is 'numpy.ndarray' will this matter?

Comment: Did you use exactly what I'm using? Including the redefinition of `a`? And after that did you try with the full path?

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly what you're using. I am not sure how to try full path? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: It's ok, this is odd - it really does work for me. What system are you on? The full path means the path to the directory you want to save the file into. For instance `D:\atru\data\ ` on Windows or the example above on Mac or Linux.   Also, instead of saving, run `pl.show()` to simply see if it's plotting anything at all.

Comment: I ran pl.show() and it shows perfect. I am on windows. It even creates an empty png file.

Comment: Briefly scrolling through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image) post and checking it out - do you have a `pl.show()` before `pl.savefig()` ?

Comment: I just realized this too. I have pl.show() before pl.savefig(). I switched those lines of code and now it works fine. Thank you very much.