# How to plot Wordlcoud for each column in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, imshow, word-cloud

I have a pandas dataframe with N rows.

Every row N has many words.

I am trying to plot wordloud for each column.

df:

```
    prediction                    text
0           1  [menu, food, food and chicken...
1           2  [transfer, money, transfer, transfer, trans...
2           0  [cold,cold,cold,hot,love...
```

code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

def show_wordcloud(data, title):

        wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40,
        scale=3,
    ).generate(str(data))


    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.axis('off')

    if title:
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)


    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.savefig('cluster{}.png'.format(title))
    plt.show()


for row in df.iterrows():
    show_wordcloud(row['text'], row["prediction"])
```

But What I get is the blank images for all the columns except for the lat one.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: images do show in jupyter notebook. They don't get saved. They also dont get shown when running .py file

Comment: Tried. Still not working

Comment: Try just after `imshow()` assign an object to the current figure and then save it: `out_fig = plt.gcf(); out_fig.savefig('cluster{}.png'.format(title))`. See: [Matplotlib (pyplot) savefig outputs blank image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9012487/1422451)

Comment: I did that too. Still only the last image is being saved,

Comment: Did you try subplots?

Comment: I tried. It worked. Thanks