# capture figure when plt.show() is not under control [python]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image) and understand that:

`plt.show()` resets the plot, so you need to `plt.savefig()` before `plt.show()`. `plt` refers to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

I wonder if there's way to capture and save the figure when you don't have control about `plt.show()` (eg, it's encapsulated).

In my specific case I'm using the `shap` package. I do

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_pred_all, show=False)
```

and `show=False` doesn't seem to work. The figure still displays.

Comment: Can you please explain "show=False doesn't seem to work". It should work as expected, so if it doesn't for you please provide a [mcve].