# How to change linewidth when saving PDF figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to generate a figure in PDF format for better quality (eps would still be good). In the figure, I need an oscillatory background, which is the actual signal, with a thin linewidth and a thicker (3 times) moving average filter line in the middle.

If I save the image in .png the desired linewidths are kept, the same does not apply for .pdf, .eps and .pgf, for which there seems to be a minimum linewidth, even though I didn't find anything in this sense on the docs. I'm running on Spyder with Python 3.7.3, updated matplotlib. I tried both to specify the linewidth into the ax.plot() call and also from rcParams but the behavior does not change: only .png keeps the correct format.

I attach the function which does the actual plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def data_plot(xaxis, sequences, xlabel, ylabel, legend, widths,
             alphas, colors, fil):

    n = len(sequences)    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

    for i in range(n):
        ax.plot(xaxis, sequences[i], linewidth=widths[i], alpha=alphas[i], 
                color=colors[i])
        ax.plot(xaxis[int(fil/2)-1:len(xaxis)-int(fil/2)], 
                np.convolve(sequences[i],np.ones(fil)/fil,mode='valid'),
                linewidth=4*widths[i], alpha=2*alphas[i], color=colors[i], 
                label=legend[i])

    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size': 12})

    plt.show()

seq = [np.random.uniform(12,14,500), np.random.uniform(11,12.5,500), 
np.random.uniform(12.7,15,500)]
x = np.linspace(1,100,500)
data_plot(x,seq,'x','y',['A','B','C'],
          [0.2,0.2,0.2],[0.5,0.4,0.3],['C0','C1','C2'],10)

plt.savefig('figure.png')
plt.savefig('figure.pdf')
```

Comment: Please telll is what linewidth you tried.

Comment: That is, always use [mcve]s when asking about undesired behaviour of code.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I called the method with this widths parameter: [0.4,0.3,0.2], but I tried to change it. If I call it with [0.1,0.1,0.1] the behavior is also more evident. This is why I would say that there exists a minimum supported.

Comment: I provided a minimal working example. The code saves the figure in .png and .pdf and to me they are different. I would like the .pdf to look like the .png image as for what described above.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I've got a similar problem.

Comment: No, no solution to this problem. I ended up saving the figure in PNG format with higher DPI and then converting it to PDF. Very poor solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case others land here, I had the same issue and it turned out it was due to the PDF viewer. Specifically, with Foxit Reader Version 11.0.0.49893; see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1CIQ.png). After uninstalling and [downgrading](https://foxit-reader.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions) to 10.1.3 linewidths display [properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzJka.png). So please check with another viewer.

However, this is not the problem with OP's script. Running it saves blank images. This is because of the `plt.show` called before `plt.savefig`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image) for explanation.
You could, for example, move the `savefig` inside the function, or return the `fig`. The linewidths will then show correctly on the saved PDF/PNG files: [saved plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKAna.png)

Pasting code below. *Increased linewidth from '4' to '20' for emphasis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def data_plot(xaxis, sequences, xlabel, ylabel, legend, widths,
             alphas, colors, fil):

    n = len(sequences)    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

    for i in range(n):
        ax.plot(xaxis, sequences[i], linewidth=widths[i], alpha=alphas[i], 
                color=colors[i])
        ax.plot(xaxis[int(fil/2)-1:len(xaxis)-int(fil/2)], 
                np.convolve(sequences[i],np.ones(fil)/fil,mode='valid'),
                linewidth=20*widths[i], alpha=2*alphas[i], color=colors[i], 
                label=legend[i])
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size': 12})

    plt.show()
    return fig


seq = [np.random.uniform(12,14,500), np.random.uniform(11,12.5,500), 
np.random.uniform(12.7,15,500)]
x = np.linspace(1,100,500)
fig = data_plot(x,seq,'x','y',['A','B','C'],
          [0.2,0.2,0.2],[0.5,0.4,0.3],['C0','C1','C2'],10)

fig.savefig('figure.png')
fig.savefig('figure.pdf')
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue: the problem is due to the thinner background noise, which is thicker in .pdf format.