# matplotlib.pyplot functions creating new figures instead of applyting to the current one

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm starting to learn matplotlib, following the [pyplot tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html), but something weird—I think—is happening in the very first part.

When I do this,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

`plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])` creates the figure, but `plt.ylabel('some numbers')` creates another figure with the label but with no plot. Nothing about this is mentioned in the tutorial, and I have been reading about the `plt` functions to see if this is supposed to happen and/or how to fix it, but can't find anything. What can I do about this?

I just installed matplotlib 3.1.3 and I'm running Python 3.7.6 on Spyder 4.0.1

I see that, in this version of Spyder, I don't need to use `plt.show()`, because all figures are shown in the 'Plots' pane.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

**I HAVEN'T FOUND AN ANSWER FOR THIS.**

If I copy and paste these two lines into my shell:

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
```

I get the label applied to the figure with the plot, as it should, but, if I execute them one at a time, I get the situation described above. I'd like to know why this is happening and if it should be happening.

Comment: You can try reversing the order. Call `ylabel` first and then `plot`.

Comment: @learner Thanks for your comment. The same thing happened but in reverse order. First, plotless figure with the y-label, and then another figure with the line but without the y-label.

Comment: Are these the only two lines you're running? Or you've some other code too?

Comment: @learner Yes, they're the only ones. I tried them after deleting all images and resetting the shell, both one at a time and then one return-key press for both, but had the same behavior described.