# Save plot image in bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Here is my code:
to plot some bar graph of some data set.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#Declaring data
year = []
relative_recurrence = []

#Open data file
f = open('relative recurrence plot.txt','r')
for row in f:
    row = row.split(' ')
    year.append(int(row[0]))
    relative_recurrence.append(float(row[1]))
    
#Plot the graph    
plt.bar(year, relative_recurrence,color = 'grey', label = 'HILDCAAS', edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(year), max(year) + 1, 5))

# Label for x-axis
plt.xlabel("YEAR")

# Label for y-axis
plt.ylabel("Relative Occurence")


plt.show()
plt.savefig('recurrence plot.png')
```

I used the savefig() command to save my plot. But it didn't work.
Getting no error, but the image saved is blank. Please tell the mistake. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343051/13145954) answer your question?

Comment: switch the order of plt.show() and plt.savefig()