# The pyplot does not save the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the code that uses pyplot function but the plot that is saved shows an empty area.
Removing variables did not give result. What is wrong??

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
print('Квадратическая функция y=ax^2+bx+c.')
a = 1 
b = 1 
c = 1 
 
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
y = a*x**2 + b*x + c  
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('mygraph.png')
print('the graph was saved')
```

Comment: put the `plt.savefig` command before `plt.show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.show()` should come after `plt.savefig()`

Explanation: `plt.show()` **clears** the whole thing, so anything afterwards will happen on a new empty figure

so try:

```py
plt.savefig('mygraph.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image

Answer (score 0):

The putting plt.savefig('mygraph.png') before plt.show() works.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
print('Квадратическая функция y=ax^2+bx+c.')
a = 1 
b = 1 
c = 1 
 
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
y = a*x**2 + b*x + c  
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('mygraph.png')
plt.show()
print('the graph was saved')
```